# Use German quotations in textbox asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to use the german quotations („I am an example“) in the textboxes and textareas of my website but just cannot do it, my keyboard is in german and when I write in Mcrosoft Word then the german quotations appear as I press the key, what I have tried is to set the language of the site as German this way from code behind:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

And in the page:

```
<%@ Page UICulture="de" Culture="de-DE"%>
```

I know I could just make a javascript keyup event that changes the symbol everytime I type the quotes character but this is maybe not the most eficient, standardized and smooth solution, is there a way to make my textboxes/areas detect my keyboard configuration as Micrsoft Word does, or another way to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: That's likely MS Word using "smart quotes", input boxes don't have the same rich interface that MS Word does, so unless there's a library that does it for you, it's likely a DIY thing.

Comment: Ok, interesting thanks for the info, I was curious about that, to the one downvoting would you help me by letting me know why you did it so I do not make the same mistake in any future questions? That wil help me to improve thank you.